# How to crawl a login protected .jsp page?

Tags: python, jsp, web-crawler

I want to crawl some data from a website with JavaServer Pages and login protection.

The problem is the login page is dynamically created. At first, I find that I can't login because I can't load the login page. The url of login page is like https://xxxx.xxxxxxx.edu.au/login/pages/login.jsp. Here is my python code:

```
def print_HTML(url):
        request = req.Request(url, headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0"})
        with req.urlopen(request) as response:
                data = response.read().decode("utf-8")
        html =  bs4.BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
        print(html.prettify())
```

Here is the output:

```
<head>
 <meta content="no-cache" http-equiv="pragma"/>
 <meta content="no-cache" http-equiv="cache-control"/>
 <meta content="0" http-equiv="expires"/>
 <noscript>
  <meta content="1;url=https://my.xxxxxxx.edu.au/studentportal/faces/home" http-equiv="refresh"/>
 </noscript>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function delayedRedirect(){
                        window.location = "https://my.xxxxxxx.edu.au/studentportal/faces/home";
                }
 </script>
 <title>
  Login redirect page
 </title>
</head>
<body onload="setTimeout('delayedRedirect()', 1000)">
 <i> 
  Redirecting to... https://my.xxxxxxx.edu.au/studentportal/faces/home
 </i>
</body>
```

After this, I go back to the last page before login which is like https://xxxxxx.xxx.xxxxxxx.edu.au, printing its html and I find the href to go to login page is https://xxxxxx.xxx.xxxxxxx.edu.au/login/saml. However, when I try to print it, it shows

```
<html>
 <head>
  <base target="_self"/>
 </head>
 <body onload="document.myForm.submit()">
  <noscript>
   <p> 
    JavaScript is required. Enable JavaScript to use OAM Server.
   </p>
  </noscript>
  <form action="https://auth.xxxxxxx.edu.au/login/pages/login.jsp" method="post" name="myForm">
   <!------------ DO NOT REMOVE ------------->
   <!----- loginform renderBrowserView ----->
   <!-- Required for SmartView Integration --> 
   <input name="contextType" type="hidden" value="external"/>
   <input name="username" type="hidden" value="string"/>
   <input name="OverrideRetryLimit" type="hidden" value="6"/>
   <input name="password" type="hidden" value="secure_string"/>
   <input name="challenge_url" type="hidden" value="https%3A%2F%2Fauth.unimelb.edu.au%2Flogin%2Fpages%2Flogin.jsp"/>
   <input name="request_id" type="hidden" value="1031689933436939677"/>
   <input name="authn_try_count" type="hidden" value="0"/>
   <input name="OAM_REQ" type="hidden" value="VERSION_4~Dx0y9HYwplTsrfWQuqCU5Y2hQlk96FnIkBSXmLxTfuyLy0XUtqGK20TF4Z7nTGFfHouR5m7KmcK96in%2f670EPaaukVhyOLld36hlyZe4ZtPW9Bvz%2bs%2fN%2fQXgcBw5z5ppJksT6HckJtxSI1TSWL5fPHKBjCQk0MuIzrxmH%2b%2fP4NnoeL73NCL4mCLoIu6NrPQ8q28kYR8Gi2Qh9i1mqOtr1QXl%2bXzeAXMS6ShA307odSH%2fT1GzsEcxTEEPKd7JLXUd8Z28iQM4t5PyVQJVHqiqTgyVxvFgiPlsrs%2bBb%2bhJ1tmCyvuPPsCc9cOsX7p1Jg0gHZkoRJjxrbYhXKVqJvAj9HhBve5zI6Hs73m6YyKyWgztO3gmlj5clBHMAzEY5EJ4MU8OojP6fxdd5cRL2GQPUQ6cGk9IV4HOSV2SPCaKdzkXGt5DwLXnMLsx3AJpiPEXptSns%2fDm%2fzPcnWbtD%2fZrFKgM%2b6hatFtlsFPk65N0fbNu1T5FMGVNioqIVBbkdcNyEHyoPmioCBXb9eB5KWXdGDudLApKy0nVdLjrYE14hRDwZstX8SkpqvKhjKB5JeiWCKuPvPe%2bWFg6ZcVftSj3UuaNaH%2f4Wst4suXGKq9t8di2e1kbJAV5pBamxkwVKrHJ9cz%2boJzqgJ5Cx6s1dxb%2brHBxTw6VJ%2f9otIlaplxNvKwilRUOhXqgoGVJxsVp5z9BDdnWt%2fzgjK8Rxq6qtQt1LfmM5pSdNB3Rn%2b6Q3S0kgofs7goOr%2bEqo1Fc3kTxn%2ffMjvASU%2fdYwFuVafahA4lkgplHT7986SdHt8V1A5dLLRSdX8PgwHMd4XlJHYEkw1Neeoog%2fG7Lq%2fysG%2bfDc5rCvjoj0gLZy%2fowUhgqYwaZvfNGLNkH7H802e0bP59Ms3IU605%2f9o7in%2bS1u3ZE3PnNabP1pu0somVqcRxz8hxOEkRbRLHZwYB%2fTNvAalywCAZ9sCwweH8tU0oFAuXwWdUDuviq8Hz%2bBWwhHEJkSfv%2b100lgRBlX6p%2b9HJYW4cqgcXU1oT%2f8qBywYHw1Ap6DmZb6L0S7MUNw%2ft8%2fg%2bO5NwGRbrOjlV0cQ4tCEU3ehZiEnXwuunjVOAfjjiyACjkfstnY7vSsFbcWEeBwtvZIW2RXFFV2qYPaS6iqZxlt0fWpV2VvL%2fb9BipKOgtJxFigvnsSa5a9THBrlBM%2byA1pNNI2dm3s18Fx68z0oIQhNDEVVx7Q7oOl5TBdUxYgU7uWrkqtKf%2flxvGrsKEmhdWModmOIiYKq2I4U6KcYmN2fogi7neh6t%2fZbg7%2bMQ%2fvQAeVOrKpJWB558DXm0qDW65msxQgmwhg6ct7D29iSOVDyLGpnrMAw5QU%2fB7jwx5OinbJ83UyGCJqTm0T9%2fm9fAq4ofjQ0p3YV62iokrCC0E0ZR7GBh6%2bFaaElOSdoL1nxdVJN2KNXTuwFgg8iK5%2fPVcoYgLsCRXGq0Dutwaf%2fp6UgjdTKHz5y0W4DO3ZTsPF4jhhWUJ%2fvtG3slDJHN1EOb78ACnrAi5S4q109xFPqj8s5U835yUdaHIMFXxMpT2pWutWtbC39p09y9LXuwUM4obMutVmA5EvYvSLqPnu3KAiMGDttfbvmkA9AjSDvV6mAwv8k9urj%2bo%2fSQkFxNt3aUD4ymERZ7ksyjQbm2ud%2f15gFvfNizTRE6JsamIWO4UICJUX6Pr7A%3d%3d"/>
   <input name="locale" type="hidden" value="en_AU"/>
   <input name="resource_url" type="hidden" value="%252Fuser%252Floginsso"/>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Is there any way I can make my python program go to the .jsp page?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

open the devtools in your browser, click network, go to the
 https://auth.xxxxxxx.edu.au/login/pages/login.jsp, log in.
check what was sent by browser in post query.
If it simple auth , just copy all post query with headers etc, 
and put all of that to the your request.
Or even more simple copy as CURL from devtoll and convert to requests
(for example here https://curl.trillworks.com/)

Comment: I tried to use a cURL-converted request but It still prints the error message like "JavaScript is required. Enable JavaScript to use OAM Server.". Is that possible  request_html which supports javascript solve this problem?